# Google Biq Query and SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm used to working with SQL Server databases and now I need to query data from BigQuery.

What is a better way to query data from the table like this?

[image]

Where one column includes several columns...

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please give an actual example of sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Hi,
I need this as a normal table with columns USER ID, AGE, Gender.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery supports `unnest()` for turning array elements into rows.  So, you can convert all of this into rows as:

```
select t.user_id, t.user_pseudo_id, up.*
from t cross join
     unnest(user_properties) up;
```

You want a field *per* property.  There are several ways to do this.  If you want exactly one value per row, you can use a subquery and aggregation:

```
select t.user_id, t.user_pseudo_id, p.*
from t cross join
     (select max(case when up.key = 'age' then up.string_value end) as age,
             max(case when up.key = 'gender' then up.string_value end) as gender
      from unnest(user_properties) up
     ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually subqueries are used like:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  user_pseudo_id,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM user_properties WHERE key = "age") AS age,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM user_properties WHERE key = "gender") AS gender,
FROM dataset.table
```